# Ограничить вывод произвольных полей WP на PHP

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Есть необходимость вывести произвольны поля wordpress, но некоторые из произвольных полей могут быть незаполнены.

Вопрос, как на PHP или средствами Wordpress ограничить вывод пустых полей?
Сейчас я убираю лишнее через JS, вот таким образом:

```
$('.element').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "") {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

Но это вроде не лучшее решение, так как пустой блок всеравно загружается.

Comment: Судя по тегам, вы подгружаете эти поля ajaxом, верно? В любом случае, нужен PHP-код, с помощью которого вы их получаете.

Comment: Нет, я загружаю полностью, а потом на уровне браузера клиента удаляю лишнее.

Comment: Покажите код, которым загружаете

Comment: Стандатрными средствами вывода полей wordpress
'<?php the_field('name_field'); ?>'

Comment: А можете дать именно фрагмент кода-то? В цикле выводите, хардкодом или еще как?

Comment: Это и есть фрагмент кода который выводит данные поля.

Comment: Этот "фрагмент" выводит все поля сразу? Хорошо, вы не могли бы показать две строчки кода до "фрагмента" и две строчки кода после (если это не секрет, конечно)

Comment: Этот код находится в цикле. Он обернут в <lI><?php the_field('name_field'); ?></li>, и таких их 60 штук. Значение 'name_field' у всех разное. Если поле в админке пустое, то и выводится оно не будет, но <li> и другие теги в которое обернут код остаются. Я его remov-лю с помоющью js. Но я хочу сделать так, чтобы код на уровне бэкнда не выводился, если тот пустой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот

```
$field_names = array('title', 'content', 'something', 'something_else'); // список полей для вывода
for($i = 0; $i < count($field_names); $i++) {
    $value = get_field($field_names[$i]);
    if($value != "") {
        print("<li>" . $value . "</li>");
    }
}
```